# NgRx effects - mapping actions to make sequential service calls and updating store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I want to pass the same action 2 successive times with different entities, for example I want to add 2 entities,

```js
this.store.dispatch(new Add(entity1));
this.store.dispatch(new Add(entity2));
```

the problem that I encountered is that I got the result of only one action (the entity 2 one)
and this is the effect of my action. I want to wait for the result of the first action before passing the second action.

```ts
@Effect()
add$ = this.actions$
  .ofType<Add>(ADD)
  .pipe(switchMap(a =>
    this.sharedService.add(a.entity, a.api)
      .pipe(map(s => new AddResult(Ok(s.id))))
  .pipe(catchError(e => of(new AddResult(Err(e)))))));
```

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use **mergeMap** instead of **switchMap**. Here is list of Map with their behaviour: [image]

```
@effect()
add$ = this.actions$
.ofType<Add>(ADD)
.pipe(mergeMap(a =>
this.sharedService.add(a.entity, a.api)
.pipe(map(s => new AddResult(Ok(s.id))))
.pipe(catchError(e => of(new AddResult(Err(e)))))));
```

Comment: Yeah thank you didn't know the differences between the maps before, i used mergeMap and it worked fine.