# Multiple actions are not dispatched

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am building simple e commerce app. 
I am trying to prevent user to loose data on page refresh. I am using defer() in this situation. If username exist in local storage it will dispatch an action which is going to find user details and also find all items from shopping cart and here is the tricky part. Although proper data is returned from http request **only one action is dispatched**
To get things worse I have very similar logic in other effect and everything is working fine. Take a look:

This is login effect, when user is authenticated it is dispatching two actions, one for setting user details and second for shopping cart initialization:

```
@Effect()
  login$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<LoginRequest>(AuthActionTypes.LoginRequest),
    switchMap(action => {
      return this.httpClient.post<UserDetails>('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/login',
        { username: action.payload.username, password: action.payload.password })
        .pipe(
          catchError(err => {    
            console.log(err)    
            this.uiService.openSnackbar(
              'Invalid username or password',
              null,
              3000
          )    
            return EMPTY;
          })
        )    
    }),
    mergeMap(userDetails => {

      localStorage.setItem("current_user_id", JSON.stringify(userDetails.id))
      localStorage.setItem("current_username", JSON.stringify(userDetails.email))

      return [
        new Login({ userDetails }),
        new ShoppingCartRequest({ userId: userDetails.id })        
      ]     
    })
  );
```

but here this is not working, notice that in merge map I am logging user details and I am sure that everything works fine with Login action:

```
  @Effect()
  findByUsername$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<FindByUsername>(AuthActionTypes.FindByUsername),
    switchMap(action => {
      return this.httpClient.get<UserDetails>(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user?username=${action.payload.username}`)
        .pipe(
          catchError(err => {    
            console.log(err)    
            return EMPTY;
          })
        )    
    }),
    mergeMap(userDetails => {

      console.log(userDetails)

      return [
        new ShoppingCartRequest({ userId: userDetails.id }),
        new Login({ userDetails })
      ] 
    })
  );
```

I am also attaching code for defer() and ShoppingCartRequest action:

```
@Effect()
  init$ = defer((): Observable<FindByUsername | Logout> => {
    const username = localStorage.getItem("current_username");

    return (username) ?
      of(new FindByUsername({ username: JSON.parse(username) })) :
      of(new Logout())    
  });

@Effect()
    initializeShoppingCart$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<ShoppingCartRequest>(ShoppingCartActionTypes.ShoppingCartRequest),
        switchMap(action => this.httpClient.get<ShoppingCart>(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/shoppingCart/${action.payload.userId}`)
            .pipe(
                catchError(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    return EMPTY
                })
            )),
        map(shoppingCart => {
            return new AddEventsToShoppingCart({ events: shoppingCart.events })
        })
    )
```

Any ideas here? Maybe I am using wrong maps there? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use concatMap or MergeMap for this scenario. SwitchMap isn't the correct choice.
Check this : [NGRX effects - mapping actions to make sequential service calls and updating store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52758894/ngrx-effects-mapping-actions-to-make-sequential-service-calls-and-updating-sto/52787584#52787584)